# What do the green rectangles mean in Qt Creator's diff viewer?

Tags: git, qt-creator, git-diff

When I preview the changes before committing to git (snapshot below), sometimes there are solid green rectangles shown in the diff viewer. I'm wondering what is their meaning?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means whitespace changes. For readability of the diff, we should avoid changing whitespaces. Should change in a separate commit.